# struts2 radio button id attribute value is changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, tags, radio-button

I have a javscript function where I need to check whether any of radio buttons are checked or not. I am doing with id attribute.

```
<s:radio id="gender" name="bean.gender" list="#{'male':'male','female':'female'}"/>
```

and in javascript am checking like this:

```
if (radVal(document.forms[0].gender) == "") {
    alert("enter gender");
    document.forms[0].gender[0].focus();
    return false;
}

function radVal(radName) {
    var radioVal = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < radName.length; i++) {
        if (radName[i].checked) {
            radioVal = radName[i].value;
        }
    }
    return radioVal;
}
```

and in runtime am seeing the id as 'gendermale' and 'genderfemale', so am unable to get the proper id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every `id` in a page must be unique, and the `<s:radio>` tag is generating multiple HTML tags, it is generating multiple `id`s;

the real mistake however is that you are looping through radio buttons like if they would be checkboxes, while they're not.

**Radio buttons allows only one choice**.

Take the element by name and read the value, to get the selected one, or empty if none is selected.

Normally you could use **dot notation** (`.`)

```
document.forms[0].bean.gender.value
```

but since your name has a dot in it, you must use the other syntax (`[""]`):

```
document.forms[0]["bean.gender"].value
```